# mysql update with data from other table

Tags: mysql

i been reading and trying  alot of the answers to similiar problem.
i need to update table test field brand with the content of field name from table brands.
i do this select to check fields that need to be update:

```
SELECT brand.name,test.`1_name` 
FROM test  INNER JOIN brand 
ON test.`1_name` LIKE CONCAT('%',brand.name,'%')
```

the above give me a result of 32000 records.
i try to use that select inside an update with

```
UPDATE `test` SET brand=(....)
```

but couldnt get it to work.

Comment: This won't work. You can't update with multiple values.

Comment: ok then i think im just gonna send 200 updates cmds to mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UPDATE `test` SET brand=(SELECT brand.name FROM test  INNER JOIN brand ON test.`1_name` LIKE CONCAT('%',brand.name,'%'))
```

The query you posted returns a collections of data (`SELECT brand.name,test.1_name`  ...`),`SET brand = ` needs a scalar value.

In other words, ensure that your query returns only one result.

Comment: that returns error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'test' for update in FROM clause